# Subspace topology on a line with negative slope in $\Bbb R_\ell\times\Bbb R_\ell$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\Bbb R_\ell$ be the set of real numbers with the lower limit topology. That is, the topology generated by $\{[a,b):a,b\in\Bbb R, a<b\}$.  Let $\Bbb R_\ell\times\Bbb R_\ell$ be the product of the lower limit topology on $\Bbb R^2$.

Now let $m<0$ and $k\in\Bbb R$ and $L=\{(x,mx+k):x\in\Bbb R\}$. I claim that the subspace topology on $L$ in $\Bbb R_\ell\times\Bbb R_\ell$ is the discrete topology.

Let $(a,c)\in L$, and consider $B=[a,b)\times[c,d)$.  $L\cap B=\{(a,c)\}$ therefore single points in $L$ are open in the subspace topology.  This result is a bit unexpected, so I wanted to check if I'm right.

Comment: This is correct. The proof really is clear pictorially, which your proof is just the symbolic translation of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true.

I'm not sure why you say that this is unexpected, but if you still do, the proof might benefit from an explicit calculation to show that the intersection is indeed a singleton.

It may be very simple, but when you have a fact you find surprising or unconvincing, you should try to find as convincing (and complete) a proof as possible. Once you have that, the clash between a (supposedly) undeniably correct proof and intuition that the fact sounds untrue should eventually be resolved, resulting in change in your intuition. That, or you will find some trouble with completing the proof, which will make some gap or mistake you (or the author of the original "proof") had made apparent. Either way, it is beneficial for your understanding.

Comment: You make a good point tomasz.  Of course, we all,at some time or another, have convinced ourselves that a statement was true when in fact was false. I was pretty convinced that my argument was correct, and I wanted to make sure that there wasn't some subtlety I was missing.